# NSSound audible clicks on loop

Tags: objective-c, loops, click, nssound

I have an NSSound that is looping, and every time it loops there is an audible 'click' sound when it replays.

I'm using these methods:

```
[sound play];
[sound setLoops:YES];
```

Is there any way to get rid of this click? I have tried to alter the wav file it is playing so that it 'fades out' at the end but it doesn't seem to be changing anything.

Thanks heaps. :)

Comment: Can you crop/cut the end of the wav file to remove the click?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that it was my wav file that did it! xD Thanks for reminding me to check! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in my wav files. Sorted now :)